# how to generate the value for properties automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, testing

I hava some POCO which have lots of properties.I have to assign the value to the property so that i can test those POCO,but it`s too verbose to to do that manually,is there any tools that can generate the value for property of POCO automatically?

Comment: what is the data source? is it database or any kind of spreadsheet?

Comment: @SamGhatak no datasource...

Comment: Then how can you automate it....u need to provide the mapper with some data to fill in, right?

Comment: Multiple approaches: 1) properties can have default value 2) use reflection to go through properties and assign something (something can be specified by attribute) 3) serialize prepared data/deserialize and assign data during test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) will do that by default if you don't mind random data being used, to use pre-set data you have to do some set-up.